# Flutter: Get data from API as List of Dictionary and show it in DropdownButton

Tags: android, ios, flutter, api, dart

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to get the API data into Flutter. The API contains a `List<Maps>` `"responseObj"` with `key` `value` pairs. I want to get that data and show it into `DropdownButton` when the app starts i.e. `initState()`. I want my output to look like this:
[image]

This is the API:
http://161.97.96.193:3333/LovLeaveRequest

Below is my code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? value;
  List<String> leaveRequest = [];

  Future<List> get() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("http://161.97.96.193:3333/LovLeaveRequest"),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return jsonData["responseObj"];
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // leaveRequest = get();
    get();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
            hint: Text('Select Type'),
            value: this.value,
            items: leaveRequest.map((item) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(item),
                value: item,
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                this.value = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem I'm getting with the commented line in `initState()` is `A value of type 'Future<List<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<String>'.`

Comment: you can store the response in a variable which is effectively a 'Future<List<dynamic>>' and also wrap your dropdown in a futureBuilder so you can process the data that comes in plus you can add a 'circularIndicatorProgress' while waiting for the response to arrive. data

Comment: Your service layer should not be passing back anything "dynamic".  Fix that there with the appropriate "is" and "as" calls.

Comment: Also, super.initState() should always be first, not last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching API responses is a hard part of work. *If you work with plain json responses, it's harder to maintain your code and your code becomes Spaghetti Code.* So, the simplest way to deal with it is to generate a model class that converts from and to JSON format.

> **I suggest you to have a look at JSON Serialization.**

Also, you should show a circular or linear whatever loading bar while fetching data so that user don't confuse with their app freezing. Here is your code modified by me.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? value;
  bool loading = true;
  List<ApiResponse> leaveRequest = [];

  void get() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("http://161.97.96.193:3333/LovLeaveRequest"),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<dynamic> data = jsonData["responseObj"];
      for (dynamic d in data) {
        leaveRequest.add(ApiResponse.fromJson(d));
      }
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    get();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        child: Center(
          child: loading
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : DropdownButton<String>(
                  hint: const Text('Select Type'),
                  value: value,
                  items: leaveRequest.map((item) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: item.value,
                      child: Text(item.value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      value = val;
                    });
                  },
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ApiResponse {
  ApiResponse({
    required this.key,
    required this.value,
  });

  int key;
  String value;

  factory ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ApiResponse(
        key: json["Key"],
        value: json["Value"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Key": key,
        "Value": value,
      };
}
```

> **Here is the bonus part.** When calling async methods within initState method, you should call like this

**Happy Coding TT**

```
@override
void initState(){
super.initState();
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
    *yourAsyncMethod();   });
}
```